# IF NOT EXISTS then INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, not-exists

I'm trying to add a value to a table but not without checking if the value already exists. This is what I have so far:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT series.seriesName 
   FROM series 
   WHERE series.seriesName='Avengers'
) 
BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO series (seriesName) VALUES 'Avengers' 
END;
```

Database is a MySQL db on Ubuntu

Comment: Also, look at [INSERT IGNORE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1361368/314291)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IGNORE` keyword here.

It could look like:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO series (seriesName) VALUES 'Avengers'
```

The important thing is to create a unique key on `seriesName` field as it seems that you want it to be unique.
`INSERT IGNORE` doesn't make the insert when key value already exists.

If you would like to be able to get id (primary key value) for row that **wasn't** inserted (already existed), you can do the following trick:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO series (seriesName) VALUES 'Avengers'
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE seriesID= LAST_INSERT_ID(seriesID)
```

Then you will be able to get the ID with `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function no matter if the row was inserted or not.

Comment: You're right, I want to seriesName field to be unique. Is it possible that I can get the seriesID (the primary key of series table) when the series is found?